# Iterating from a file to a 2d array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I am attempting to read in a file and generate a 2d array from the files contents.

I have the following as my instance variables and my constructor

```java
private int[][] matrix;
    private boolean isSquare;

    //Constructors
    public MagicSquare(String filename)
    {
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            int dimensions = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            int row = 0;
            int col = 0;
            this.matrix = new int[dimensions][dimensions];
            while (scan.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = scan.nextLine();

                Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);

                while (row < dimensions)
                {
                    this.matrix[row][col++] = lineScan.nextInt();
                    row++;
                }
                lineScan.close();
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

when I try and run this through the testing software I end up with the following results

```
Expected :
             4              9              2 
             3              5              7 
             8              1              6 
Returned :
             4              0              0 
             0              9              0 
             0              0              2
```

which is leading me to believe I am doing something wrong in my iteration any tips or hints as to where I should be looking?

Comment: You increment both the row and the column at effectively the same time.

Comment: should i increment row outside the while loop? because that ends up throwing the entire thing way more out of whack than what I have now i'm wondering if I should explore a for loop here instead of a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment both the row and the column at effectively the same time, once for each number you read:

```
            while (row < dimensions)
            {
                this.matrix[row][col++] = lineScan.nextInt();
                row++;
            }
```

Instead, guard the loop on `col`, and increment `row` afterwards, and reset `col` to zero:

```
            while (col < dimensions)
            {
                this.matrix[row][col++] = lineScan.nextInt();
            }
            row++;
            col = 0;
```

Note that the loop is more cleanly written as a `for` loop:

```
            for (int col = 0; col < dimensions; ++col)
            {
                this.matrix[row][col] = lineScan.nextInt();
            }
            row++;
```

and you can also write your outer loop as a for loop as well:

```
for (int row = 0; scan.hasNextLine(); ++row)
// instead of while (scan.hasNextLine()) and incrementing row separately.
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/7VybBY)

Comment: This is probably along the right track but gets me a whole bunch of index out of bounds errors